# Screen multiuser - Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, gnu-screen

I'm trying to send input to a screen session from php. So far I have followed the steps explained here
[Is running GNU Screen suid root the only way to make multiuser mode work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366707/is-running-gnu-screen-suid-root-the-only-way-to-make-multiuser-mode-work)

And I have set "multiuser on" and "acladd www-data" in the screenrc file (or well, no. in another file that I use by the -c option but still)

My problem now is that whenever i try to acess screen by php

```
exec('screen -S user/session -p 0 -X stuff "test"'."\n", $ret);
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot opendir /var/run/screen/S-user: Permission denied
```

Comment: I have no idea why a question about using php belongs on this site rather than stackoverflow.. but apparently it does

Comment: You're doing it wrong. ...that aside, maybe you will find this useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/what-are-other-ways-to-share-a-tmux-session-between-two-users

Comment: I unfortunately didn't

Answer (score 0):

Permissions, Permissions, Permissions

The user that is running the PHP Interpreter does not have the required permissions to access the screen session that you have running.

You have given the user www-data permission to use the screen, however, access to the screen file is denied. Try and modify the permissions for the file to allow the www-data user to read/write.

Comment: I figured that much, what I didn't figured was how to give it, if the dir itself has any other permission than 700 screen won't run